# dplyr: Gather data from *many* SQLite data bases

Tags: r, sqlite, dplyr

Your data is stored in a large number of SQLite data base files.
You would like to gather the data from one table across all these database files.

Is this possible using `dplyr`, or `tidyverse`?

**Example Data:**

```
# Required Libraries
require('tidyverse')
require('RSQLite')
require('pool')
require('here')

# Create the dummy data
test <- data.frame(t(replicate(2,sample(0:10,4,rep=TRUE))))

fn <- here::here('1testing.sqlite3')
con <- dbPool(drv = RSQLite::SQLite(), 
              dbname = fn)
write_result = dbWriteTable(con, "TEST", test)
poolClose(con)
rm(con)

# Create multiple SQLite databases
fn = here::here('1testing.sqlite3')
file.copy(from=fn, to=here::here('2testing.sqlite3'))
file.copy(from=fn, to=here::here('3testing.sqlite3'))
```

**NOTE:** The accepted answer suggests creating a user-defined-function (UDF).  within this you could merge and process data from several tables, returning the end result.

Comment: Why don't you try using `sqldf` package and `SQL query` to merge data in the format you want? It would be good if you share some toy table examples and expected output .

Comment: @MKR, The answer I've given has data I'll try make the dataset small and show the results.  What advantages does `sqldf` offer?

Comment: [dbplyr](http://dbplyr.tidyverse.org/index.html) might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible.
The key parts are:

1. Write a function to hold the DB processing logic.
2. Use `map` within `mutate`, to invoke your custom function
3. Convert the file names from factors to strings.

Example:

```
# Required libraries
require('tidyverse')
require('RSQLite')
require('pool')
require('here')

# User defined function to read+process the data
# Files that raise errors or warnings will have NA
gather_data <- function(fn) {
  dat = tryCatch({
          print(paste0('Processing ', fn))
          db <- dbPool(drv = RSQLite::SQLite(), dbname = fn)
          tblsmry <- db %>% tbl('TEST') %>% collect()
          tblsmry
        }, 
        error=function(e){print(e); return(as.data.frame(NA))},
        warning=function(e){print(e); return(as.data.frame(NA))},
        finally={
          if(exists('db') & db$valid ){ poolClose(db); rm(db) }
        }
      )
  if(exists('dat')){return(as.data.frame(dat))}else{return(as.data.frame(NA))}
}

# Collate the data
results <- data.frame( FILE = list.files(path = here::here(), pattern = '*testing.sqlite3$', full.names = FALSE) ) %>%
  mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
  mutate(res = map(FILE, gather_db_data)) %>%
  unnest()
```

**Output:**

```
> results
              FILE X1 X2 X3 X4
1 1testing.sqlite3  1  3  0  9
2 1testing.sqlite3  2  0  5  1
3 2testing.sqlite3  1  3  0  9
4 2testing.sqlite3  2  0  5  1
5 3testing.sqlite3  1  3  0  9
6 3testing.sqlite3  2  0  5  1
```